# xsi:schemaLocation element type not bound

Tags: xml, schema

Pretty new to xml. Validator throws an error.

full error The prefix "xsi" for attribute "xsi:schemaLocation" associated with an element type "mpreader" is not bound.

Heres a clip of the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<mpreader xmlns="C:\Users\Dallan\Desktop\Mpreader\" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/20one/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xsi:SchemaLocation="C:\Users\Dallan\Desktop\Mpreader\mpreaderschemafinal.xsd"> 

            <firmware>"3.4.16"</firmware>  
            <hardware>"2.3.53"</hardware>
            <sn>"234-1three5"</sn>
```

and also a clip of the xsd

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="C:Users/Dallan/Desktop/Mpreader/" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="C:\Users\Dallan\Desktop\Mpreader\">

<xs:element name="mpreader">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:element name="firmware" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="hardware" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="sn" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="devices">
        </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Can you try to add 'targetNamespace="C:\Users\Dallan\Desktop\Mpreader\" ' to your xsd in the xs:schema element?

Comment: did not work. Do I have the syntax correct for the <mpreader> tag? thats what the validator seems to be having a problem with

Comment: My guess is that it is a namespace problem. that's why I suggested that. Maybe another think you can try to verify it, is to remove the default namespace and namespace location from your XML. We then know if it is indeed the namespace or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue where I had a custom XML I needed to parse with JAXB.

For it to parse correctly I needed to add `xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"` and `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` namespaces.

I changed this:

```
<notifications xmlns="http://some/namespace">
```

to this:

```
<notifications xmlns="http://some/namespace" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

I think in your case you may need to add both of them where they are missing.